# load a php extension

Tags: php

I would like to load into memory this library: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mailparse.php
http://pecl.php.net/package/mailparse

The web host won't install it permanently but is there a way I can load it into my script at run time?

I see this function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php

In the documentation they have a code snippet that looks right:

```
if (!extension_loaded("mailparse")) {
    dl("mailparse.so");
}
```

Is it what I should use? Is it possible?

Thanks,

Mat

Comment: The function you are using for what you about to do is no longer supported by php 5.3 which is probably what you are using

Comment: Yes it seems so - what should I be doing?

Comment: I think it a security restriction